# Suppose $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}a_n $ and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}b_n$ are series with positive terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose 
$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}a_n $ and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}b_n$ are series with positive terms. Prove that if  $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{a_{n}}{b_n} )>0$ then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}a_n $  converges if and only if $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}b_n$ converges.

I try to use the definition of the limit.

Thank you.

Comment: This is known as "Limit Comparison Test" whose proof is very well known.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\frac{a_n}{b_n}=c>0$ implies that for any $\varepsilon\in(0,c)$ there is some $N_\varepsilon$ ensuring
 $$ c-\varepsilon \leq \frac{a_n}{b_n} \leq c+\varepsilon $$
for any $n\geq N_\varepsilon$. I leave to you to finish the proof through this lemma.